# How to get width and height of an image in PB

Tags: height, width, powerbuilder

I'm using PB8.0 and I want to get the width and height of a picture to resize my picture in DW. Do you know how to get it?

I search an example to get width and height of a bitmap file. It seems correct with bitmap file but not for other such as .jpg, .gif

Please help me

```
//Getting a Bitmaps Width and Height 
int     li_job
blob    b
string  ls_ext

ls_ext = lower(Right(as_filename, 3))
CHOOSE CASE ls_ext
  CASE 'bmp'
    li_job = FileOpen( "filename.bmp", StreamMode!, Read! )
    IF li_job > 0 THEN
      FileRead( li_job, b )

      arl_Width  = Long(Integer( BlobMid( b, 19, 2 ) ), &
                   Integer( BlobMid( b, 21, 2) ) )
      arl_Height = Long(Integer( BlobMid( b, 23, 2 ) ), &
                   Integer( BlobMid( b, 25, 2) ) )
      FileClose( li_job )
    ELSE
      RETURN -1
    END IF
  CASE ELSE
    RETURN -1
END CHOOSE
RETURN 1
```

Thanks

Comment: I only have one comment on The answer of @richard-tun, the String() function needs to specify the {,encoding} parameter to be not default (EncodingUTF16LE!) and to be (encodingANSI!) instead; if the OS language is Unicode. So the first 3 marks on the jpg file can read correctly. Here is below example to reflect my Arabic OS, run PB 11.1: String (BlobMid (lb_Data, 1,3),encodingANSI!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the code to get the width and height of JPG:

```
//JPG

li_file = FileOpen(as_file_name, StreamMode!, Read! )
If li_file = -1 Then Return 0

li_read = FileRead (li_file, lb_data)  

If String (BlobMid (lb_Data, 1,3)) = Char (255) + Char (216) + Char (255) Then //JPG

    ll_DataLen = Len(lb_Data)   
    ll_DataPos = 3
    ll_FilePos = 3
    lb_LoopFlag = true
    Do While lb_LoopFlag
        ll_DataPos = ll_DataPos + 1
        ll_FilePos = ll_FilePos + 1
        li_Char1 = Asc (String (BlobMid(lb_Data, ll_DataPos, 1)))
        li_Char2 = Asc (String (BlobMid(lb_Data, ll_DataPos + 1, 1)))

        If li_Char1 = 255 And li_Char2 <> 255 Then
            If li_Char2 >= 192 And li_Char2 <= 195 Then
                al_width = Asc (String (BlobMid (lb_Data, ll_DataPos + 7,1))) * 256 + Asc (String (BlobMid (lb_Data, ll_DataPos + 8,1)))
                al_height= Asc (String (BlobMid (lb_Data, ll_DataPos + 5,1))) * 256 + Asc (String (BlobMid (lb_Data, ll_DataPos + 6,1))) 
                lb_LoopFlag= False
            Else   
                ll_FilePos = ll_FilePos + Asc (String (BlobMid(lb_Data, ll_DataPos + 3, 1))) + Asc (String (BlobMid(lb_Data, ll_DataPos + 2, 1))) + 1
                If ll_FilePos > ll_FileLength Then   
                    Exit   
                Else
                    FileSeek(li_file, ll_FilePos)   
                    FileRead(li_file, lb_Data)   
                    ll_DataLen = Len(lb_Data)   
                    ll_DataPos = 0   
                End If   
            End If   
        End If

        If ll_DataPos = ll_DataLen - 9 And lb_LoopFlag = True Then   
            ll_FilePos = ll_FilePos - 9   
            FileSeek(li_file, ll_FilePos)   
            FileRead(li_file, lb_Data)   
            ll_DataLen = Len(lb_Data)   
            ll_DataPos = 0   
        End If
        If ll_FilePos >= ll_FileLength Then   
            lb_LoopFlag = False   
        End If   
    Loop
End If
```

For GIF:

```
al_width = Asc(String (BlobMid (lb_Data, 7,1))) + Asc (String (BlobMid (lb_Data, 8,1))) * 256
al_height = Asc (String (BlobMid (lb_Data, 9,1))) + Asc (String (BlobMid (lb_Data, 10,1))) * 256
```

Answer (score 3):

The offset of the image size depends on the file format. The values that your are using are valid for the [BMP format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format), but will be different for another format.

You need to search separately for any of the file formats you need to handle. Some infos are available [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats). A similar example for VB to handle JPEG, GIF, BMP, & PNG is available [here](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=112).

Also, you could get some info via the Windows image API, but I have no example available.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to add a Picture control to a window with visible property unchecked and OriginalSize checked.

Set the picture name to load the image and Height and Width will be available to do your processing.

```
// p_1 is not visible
p_1.PictureName = "c:\temp\pbHowTo.jpg"

MessageBox("height", p_1.height)
MessageBox("width", p_1.width)
```

You may need to convert the values in pixel since they are in PbUnit.

```
height_pixel = UnitsToPixels(p_1.height, YUnitsToPixels!)
width_pixel =  UnitsToPixels(p_1.width, XUnitsToPixels!)
```

The Picture control supports .BMP, GIF, .JPG and PNG files.